# Помогите составить sql запрос чтобы вывести общую сумму полей

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Допустим есть база:

```
+-----------+---------+
| name | count 
+-----------+---------+
| Иванов | 5 | 
| Петров | 4 | 
| Васичкин | 3 |
| Иванов | 10 |
| Иванов | 5 |
```

Как в конечном итоге составить запрос так, чтобы вывести общую сумму значения "Иванов":

```
+-----------+---------+
| name | count 
+-----------+---------+
| Иванов | 20 | 
| Петров | 4 | 
| Васичкин | 3 |
```

Answer (score 6):

Это элементарный запрос с `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT name
     , SUM(count) AS count
  FROM users
 GROUP BY name
;
```

Результат:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s3gkbncX9vu9WDd58rcJ5a/0.

Answer (score 1):

Если полностью придерживаться задачи:

> Как в конечном этоге составить запрос так что бы вывел общею сумму значения "Иванов "

то нужно добавить where name like 'Иванов'

```
SELECT `name`, SUM(`count`) AS `count`
FROM `users` WHERE name LIKE 'Иванов'
GROUP BY `name`;
```

Answer (score -2):

select count(name) from DATABASENAME where name = 'Иванов'

Comment: это вобще не понятно что...

Comment: перевожу: выбрать количество(name) из базы ИМЯ БАЗЫ где name равно 'Иванов'. И получишь количество Ивановых. Если есть ещё вопросы, спрашивай.

Comment: *перевожу* Перевести мы и сами можем не хуже многих прочих. Непонятно, как делать запрос в БАЗУ.

Comment: Это шутка? А что выше написано?

Comment: ваш ответ вобще о другом, перечитайте вопрос